# TYPO3 Extension don't get Records

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I had create an extension, like this Tutorial https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/fluid_styled_content/7.6/AddingYourOwnContentElements/Index.html

In my Fluid-Template I get only:

```
array(2 items)
   data => array(105 items)
   current => NULL
```

"data" have all fields of tt_content. I have also a field "Pages", where I can say from which General Storage the datasets come from. But I cannot get the Records push to the Fluid-Template. On the DataProcessor I can't use the Repository and my Controller isn't used.

What do I wrong?

Comment: Sounds like you are mixind up two things here. The tutorial you linked is for creating a new content element (like a text & image element for example). A Controller and a Repository are mainly used in plugins. So are you trying to add a plugin or a new content element?

Comment: What is the different between Content Element and Plugin? I believed thats the same!

Comment: Content Elements are those that you can select when you create a new content element in the backend. For example text, header, login form etc. There is also the content element "Plugin". You can register a new plugin to be available in this content element. A Plugin is mostly used if you need to implement some kind of logic or want to work with records other than the mere content.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks for your Answer!